# Boot problem after ugrading Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: upgrade, boot-repair, 23.10

I am hoping someone may be able to help. I am having a problem booting after upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to 23.10

The OS I was upgrading was installed on nvme0n1 but I also had a second copy of Ubuntu on sda. That may have been the cause of the problem.

In addition I have 3 other disks:
sdb - a data disk (It had windows 10 on it at one point)
sdc and sdc - external date drives for backup"

When I boot up from the updated drive I get: "gave up waiting for root file system device" and "ALERT! /dev/nvme0n1p2 does not exist".

Any suggestions of what I need to do? I am a novice.

I have run Boot repair and the output is at https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BzMyPnt524/

I followed the advice (from lines 1957 to the last line 1970 in the paste bin link) and unfortunately it screwed up grub so that I could only boot to the grub prompt.

I didn’t know how to take it from there so I decided to reinstall Ubuntu as I had my data backed up.

I now have a working system - although all the snap apps are broken. But that is another issue.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: from lines 1957 to the last line 1970 in your paste bin link it offers advice on how to fix - what steps have you taken with the advice provided. [edit] in to your question for additional clarity.

Comment: "upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to 23.10" is not supported. You can only upgrade from one release to the next, or from an LTS to the next LTS. The safest option would be to back up your files, then reinstall

Comment: Try unplugging the unrelated drives, then reinstall GRUB with https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/1004020

Comment: It looks like your data is still there: `======================== nvme0n1p2/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================` However it's not the partition you thought...